# Unordered List, removing active state from <li> and transferring to another

Tags: jquery, css

i'm sorry if the titles confusing, here's what i'm trying to do. I have an `<ul>` and i want to make it so when i click on one of the `<li>`, that item becomes `id="active"`, removing the old `<li>` item that had that id, thereby taking on the css for `id="active"`. I hope this makes sense. Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/20i6h5cs

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "removing the old `<li>` item that had that id" do you mean you want to remove the entire element or simply remove the id from it?

Comment: I have to agree with Jon and Anthony - you should use class for this. An id is intended to be a unique identifier for an element, not an arbitrary marker. And while this use is not the original intention of the class attribute, either, this sort of use has become standard practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll echo Jon's suggestion that you use a class, rather than an ID. However, if you did insist on going the ID route, something like this:

```
$('.ulSideNav li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('active').id = null;
    this.id = 'active';
});
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that worked out perfectly. Unfortunately, changing the way it was done would be a huuuuuge pain. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use a `class` instead of an `id` for this purpose (jQuery makes it easier as well). It would look like this:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.active)", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

The above installs a delegated handler on `ul` that gets invoked whenever a descendant `li` without the class gets clicked. The handler adds the class to the clicked element and removes it from all of its siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle to start you out:

http://jsfiddle.net/avvKe/